# iOS comparing NSDictionaries in Arrays

Tags: string, ios6, character-encoding, nsdictionary

I'm trying to find the index of an NSDictionary in an Array with NSDictionaries, but having problems with the encoding of the two.

Array a: is downloaded from a webserver (as a csv-string) and then converted into an Array of dictionaries.

Array b: is loaded with [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile] from a plist.

The dictionaries and arrays look good, but [indexOfObject] doesn't give me any results.

By outputting the data to the console, I found out that German Umlauts are encoded differently.

Array a: shows the character «ä» as \U00c3\U00a4
Array b: shows the character «ä» as \U00e4

So I guess that's why the function returns a NSNotFound.

I tried to cast the strings in many different ways, with no result...

Interestingly, the function used to work...

Any Ideas?

[EDIT]

Well, it turns out I didn't process the data coming from the server correctly.

I had to change this

```
NSString *dataStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

into this:

```
NSString *dataStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you aren't honouring the content-encoding used by the web server in its HTTP response when creating the `NSString` objects...

Comment: There is no content-encoding, really. All I get is a plain CSV-String. And I don't see any possibility to convert the incoming string...

Comment: Appologies; it should be the `charset` attribute of the `Content-Type` response header field.

Comment: This says, Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8 - so this should be fine...?

Comment: OMG... Sorry, my bad... I had to change the received-Data encoding (of course) [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction!